# Lucene seach multiple or single field based on search string

Tags: hibernate, lucene

I have one jsp with text box to enter search  and object contains two fields title,description.
Here if we enter like title:'Rin' in search box it should search only title and if 'Rin' then should search ib both fields.please help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have two fields title, description in your index and you want to fire two different queries on lucene index based on your text box input?

```
1) search box input = "title:Rin"
   query = "title:Rin"

2) search box input = "Rin"
   query = "title:Rin OR description:Rin"  
   you can also use BooleanQuery with Occur.SHOULD for preparing your query.
```

In your JSP/UI code manipulate what was passed in text box (with 'title:' or without) and create lucene query based on that.

In my opinion its a poor user experience, you should have one text box and couple of "check boxes" with field names (like check box for title, check box for description) or multi select box or something equivalent.